# How to get values from a string dict list in sql bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I have a sql table with the following data

| Outbound click |
| --- |
| [{'action_type': 'outbound_click', 'value': '1025'}] |

How do I get the just the value as this is a string in bigquery sql?

I want the output to be

| Outbound click |
| --- |
| 1025 |

Comment: I usually use `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` to get the value of the json like structure.

to get value of `value` field, you can use


`SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_column, '$[0].value') AS value
FROM your_table;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just UNNEST the array then extract the json value to get 1025. See approach below:

```
with sample_data as (
select array(select "{'action_type': 'outbound_click', 'value': '1025'}") as arr_data
)

select 
  JSON_VALUE(json_data, '$.value') as outbound_click 
from sample_data, 
  unnest(arr_data) as json_data
```

Output:

[image]